# Problems with Netbeans & Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, primefaces

I've been working for a few weeks now with some web tecnologies, but i have had some issues with Netbeans when I use primefaces. I usually do my "test beans" in one "test project" and they work fine, but then when I copy my "test beans" into my "main project" i get a lot of issues, and my projects just wont work at all. 
Anyone has any idea of why this happens?

Comment: The answer would depend on the *issues* that you're facing.

Comment: well, sometimes my projects run but they wont work the way they are supposed to or they wont work at all, I've checked this with my teacher and he has no clue, he says my logic its fine but somehow my beans wont start or comunicate with the jsf

Comment: then create a test project, copy your beans to your main project, try to run it and post the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with Netbeans and I had similar problems...The problem was the primefaces library that the Netbens had. The JARs was corrupted. Change the default primefaces library of Netbeans for the official [jars](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html). It worked for me :)

Comment: Thx a lot man, seems to be working now, I'm still having some problems, but i have not had the time to try with patience, i hate school i cant learn what i want when i want